# Heroku pipelines with react stormpath

Tags: reactjs, heroku, pipeline, stormpath

I created app with react and express (client-side rendering). I use **react-stormpath**.
When I added `https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com` into **Authorized Origin URIs** in Stormpath Admin it works ok. But when I created pipeline with review apps, it created new subdomain with every request e.g. `https://my-app-name-pr-1.herokuapp.com` and there is problem with CORS, because this new url is not in Authorized Origin URIs.
And I can't use wildcards like: `https://*.herokuapp.com`.

Some hints how to manage it? Because I really don't want to add new Authorized Origin on every pull request.

Really thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inability to use wildcards for the Authorized Origin URIs is a bug that we are fixing, the fix should go out soon.  If you need to work around this issue ASAP you can use one of our SDKs (like the Stormpath Node SDK) to programmatically add URLs the the application.

Comment: Really thanks for soo fast answer!
This issue is not urgent, so I will wait for release.
Do you plan something like reg-ex for uri in the future? I mean for example: `my-app-pr-[1-9].herokuapp.com`, because `*.herokuapp.com` allow access to all herokuapp-developers.

Comment: No prob!  Today's release just went live, and it appears that the wildcards are now working, can you confirm that it's working for you as well?  Regarding the regex request, that's a good idea, would you mind adding that to https://ideas.stormpath.com/ - thanks!

Comment: Sure, I will test it and give you feedback. And I will add issue about reg-ex to ideas too.